# How to center a dropdown menu item?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am started to use the wordpress theme "Pinnacle Theme" and optimized it for my needs. But now i got a problem i cant solve and hoped someone can help here.

I am trying to center the Large Menu (more Columns, then normal dropdown) to the parent item.

On my [Website "Wilde-NaTouren"](https://wilde-natouren.de/) the Menu Item "Wandern + Trekking" is the Problem.

The normal ".kt-lgmenu" is normally full-width, but i try to give it a fixed width with following code

`.kad-primary-nav .sf-menu>.kt-lgmenu>ul {
    width: 520px!important;
}`

now i have to center the `.kt-lgmenu>ul` to `.sf-menu>.kt-lgmenu` but i dont know how.

Here 2 Images to view how it looks right now, and what i want to have (sorry cant post Images).

[Actual Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a08mP.jpg) ->
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbmU6.jpg)

Thanks for your Help

Comment: Can you post your nav HTML and the CSS?

Comment: Just linked to the website... there are too much CSS Files and loaded stuff from wordpress. But the Question is answered by Andy Hoffman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a relative `li` container already, which is the first step. The next step is to horizontally center the hidden dropdown using `transformX`:

```
.sf-dropdown-menu {
  …
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

I edited the site in the inspector and recorded it to show you how each rule is applied.

[image]

First, the `left: 50%` is applied. Then, we perform the negative translation. `left` refers to the parent element while `transform` refers to the target element (the actual hidden `ul`).

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!

Used it on `.kad-primary-nav .sf-menu>.kt-lgmenu>ul`


Complete Code:
`
.kad-primary-nav .sf-menu>.kt-lgmenu>ul {
    width: 520px!important;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
`